# Unable to set state on nested object reactjs

Tags: reactjs, input, state, onchange, nested-object

I'm having issues with updating the state of a nested object from an input.

Updated with more code. I am trying to build a multi step form. First page takes team information, second page takes player information.

Parent component:

```
export class MainForm extends Component {
state = {
    step: 1,
    teamName: '',
    teamManagerName: '',
    teamManagerEmail: '',
    player: [{
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        height: ''
    }]
}

// proceed to next step
nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        step: step + 1
    })
}

// go to previous step
prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        step: step - 1
    })
}

// handle fields change
handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({[input]: e.target.value});
}

render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    const { teamName, teamManagerName, teamManagerEmail, player: { firstName, lastName, email, height}} = this.state;
    const values = {teamName, teamManagerName, teamManagerEmail, player: { firstName, lastName, email, height}};

    switch(step) {
        case 1:
            return (

                <FormTeamDetails
                    nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    values={values}
                />
                )
        case 2:
            return (
               <FormPlayerDetails
                    nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    prevStep={this.prevStep}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    values={values}
               />
            )
        case 3:
            return (
                <Confirm
                    nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    prevStep={this.prevStep}
                    values={values}
           />
            )
        case 4:
            return (
                <h1>Scuccess!</h1>
            )
    }

}
```

}

This next code snippet is the first page of the form and one of the child components. The handleChange function successfully does its job here.

```
export class FormTeamDetails extends Component {
continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
}

render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
        <Container>
            <Form>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="teamName">Team Name</Label>
                    <Input 
                        type="teamName" 
                        name="teamName" 
                        onChange={handleChange('teamName')} 
                        defaultValue={values.teamName} />
                    <Label for="teamManagerName">Team Manager Name</Label>
                    <Input 
                        type="teamManagerName" 
                        name="teamManagerName" 
                        onChange={handleChange('teamManagerName')} 
                        defaultValue={values.teamManagerName}
                        />
                    <Label for="teamManagerEmail">Team Manager Email</Label>
                    <Input 
                        type="teamManagerEmail" 
                        name="teamManagerEmail" 
                        onChange={handleChange('teamManagerEmail')} 
                        defaultValue={values.teamManagerEmail} />

                    <Button 
                        label="Next"
                        // primary="true"
                        onClick={this.continue}
                        style={{float: 'right'}}>Next</Button>
                </FormGroup>
            </Form>
        </Container>

    )
}
```

}

This is the second page of the form, and where I'm having issues:

```
export class FormPlayerDetails extends Component {
continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
}

back = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
}

render() {
    const { values: { player }, handleChange, values } = this.props;

    return (
        <Container>
            <h3>Add players</h3>
            <Form>
            <Row form>
                <Col md={3}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="firstName" 
                    name="firstName" 
                    id="firstName" 
                    placeholder="First Name" 
                    defaultValue={values.player.firstName} 
                    onChange={handleChange('values.player.firstName')} 
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="lastName" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name"  />
                </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </FormGroup>
                </Col>
            </Row>

            <Row form>
                <Col>
                <Button 
                        label="Back"
                        // primary="true"
                        onClick={this.back}
                        style={{float: 'left'}}>Back</Button>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                <Button 
                        label="Next"
                        // primary="true"
                        onClick={this.continue}
                        style={{float: 'right'}}>Next</Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>

            </Form>
        </Container>

    )
}
```

}

I'm unable to update the player property with the input values.  Also, I would like to add multiple player input fields in this component. I would like at least 5 players to be added to the team, hence the player array in the parent component. Please let me know if I should go about this in another way. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are passing a string instead of the variable to your `handleChange` function.

Comment: I changed it to: onChange={handleChange(values.player.firstName)} , but am still not able to set it

Comment: Also, apart from my first comment, your method for updating the state seems wrong. In this current shape, it creates a player first name with the given value from the input. It does not update the player array in your state. So, please share some more code with us. How do you pass the props and what is your intention with that input?

Comment: What do you mean not working? Is the function not called / it is passing the wrong value so that the state is updated wrongly / the value is correct but the state is not updated? You can add a console.log in `handleChange` to check. :)

Comment: Updated the main post with more code :) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `player` property in your state is an array but you are treating it as an object. So, I assume there will be one player and it will be an object. Here is one solution for your case. But it feels like you are struggling with many unnecessary things there like passing values, etc since you have already `name` attribute for your inputs. I don't know, maybe you are thinking about other situations.

Here is the `handleChange` part:

```
handleChange = input => e => {
  const { target } = e;
  if (input === "player") {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      player: {
        ...prev.player,
        [target.name]: target.value
      }
    }));
  } else {
    this.setState({ [input]: target.value });
  }
};
```

Here is the input part:

```
<Input
  type="firstName"
  name="firstName"
  id="firstName"
  placeholder="First Name"
  defaultValue={values.player.firstName}
  onChange={handleChange("player")}
/>
```

As you can see, I'm passing the `handleChange` the `player` property and get the `name` from your input. Then in the `handleChange` method, using the functional state and spread syntax, I'm updating the `player`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    step: 1,
    teamName: "",
    player: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: ""
    }
  };

  handleChange = input => e => {
    const { target } = e;
    if (input === "player") {
      this.setState(prev => ({
        player: {
          ...prev.player,
          [target.name]: target.value
        }
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState({ [input]: target.value });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Input handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { handleChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>firstName</span>
          <input
            type="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            id="firstName"
            onChange={handleChange("player")}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>team</span>
          <input
            type="teamName"
            name="teamName"
            onChange={handleChange("teamName")}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Here is the updated version of the `players` as an array (be careful about the plural name). So, in this naive version, we keep a `players` array with some unique `id`'s on them. This is how we are going to target the updated player. Check each `input`, there is an `id` now and we set it to the `player`'s one. In the `handleChange` function, this time we are mapping the `players` (so a new array is returned), then if the `id` matches with our player's one, we are updating its relevant property. If the `id` does not match, we are returning the original `player` without doing anything.

The `handleChange` part is the one you need to focus on. We are mapping and rendering the inputs by using each `player`'s properties in the `Input` component. It seems a little bit confusing but if you look into it deeply you can understand. We are using `Object.entries` to map the properties but before that, we are cleaning the `id` one since we don't want to display it.

You can find the working snippet below.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    step: 1,
    teamName: "",
    players: [
      {
        id: 1,
        firstName: "foo",
        lastName: "foo's lastname",
        email: "foo@foo.com"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        firstName: "bar",
        lastName: "bar's lastname",
        email: "bar@bar.com"
      }
    ]
  };

  handleChange = input => e => {
    const { target } = e;
    if (input === "players") {
      this.setState({
        players: this.state.players.map(player => {
          if (player.id === Number(target.id)) {
            return { ...player, [target.name]: target.value };
          }

          return player;
        })
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ [input]: target.value });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Input handleChange={this.handleChange} players={this.state.players} />
        <div>
          {this.state.players.map(player => (
            <div>
              <h3>Player {player.id}</h3>
              <div>First Name: {player.firstName}</div>
              <div>Last Name: {player.lastName}</div>
              <div>Email: {player.email}</div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { handleChange, players } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {players.map(player => {
          const { id, ...playerWithoutId } = player;
          return (
            <div key={player.id}>
              <h3>Player {player.id}</h3>
              {Object.entries(playerWithoutId).map(([key, value]) => (
                <div>
                  <span>{key}</span>
                  <input
                    name={key}
                    id={player.id}
                    onChange={handleChange("players")}
                    defaultValue={value}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thank you! However, firstName is still not getting updated from the input value after handleChange is executed. Also, can you explain to me how ...prev.player works? I'm still very new to js. Thank you!

Comment: You can see my snippet. It is working for my case. Just change the related parts according to that. Don't forget to change the `player` in your state. It should be an object, not an array. `prev` part is related to functional update for `setState` and `...` is the spread syntax. Just google them :) If you have still questions, I'll try to explain it.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked! Originally I had `player` defined as an array instead of an object, because in my PlayerForm, I wanted the user to have the ability to enter information for multiple players. With `player` as an object, how would I be able to take inputs for multiple players?

Comment: You can't do it if you keep the player info as an object. I've updated my answer and added one version using an array for players.

Comment: Your solutions worked seamlessly. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For FormPlayerDetails, you dont need to pass complete values, instead you just need to pass values.players. And since your players attribute is a table... use a map function instead